Sampling angles on a sphere: From a general covariance matrix to concentration parameter
I am trying to extract points on a sphere in python.
I have to localise event in the sky and produce a map using healpy.
During the test session I used the von Mises-Fisher since I assumed that variance for $'\theta'$ is the same as the one for $'\phi'$. All worked well and I was able to obtain a concentration parameter $'k'$ by using $'k=1/\sigma^2'$.
My function to evaluate the probability in a pixel was
def Mises_Fisher(theta,phi,DS_theta,DS_phi,conc):
    meanvec=hp.ang2vec(DS_theta,DS_phi)
    meanvec=np.asarray(meanvec,dtype=np.float128)
    norm=np.sqrt(np.dot(meanvec,meanvec))
    meanvec=meanvec/norm
    
    var=hp.ang2vec(theta,phi)
    var=np.asarray(var,dtype=np.float128)
    norm=np.sqrt(np.dot(var,var))
    var=var/norm
    
    factor=np.dot(conc*var,meanvec)
    factor=np.float128(factor)
    #Normalization is futile, we will devide by the sum
    #fullnorm=conc/(2*np.pi*(np.exp(conc)-np.exp(-conc)))
    ret=np.float128(np.exp(factor))#/fullnorm
    #ret=factor
    return ret

and then for each pixel in the healpy map, I can assign a probability.
Now I have a covariance matrix that is no more isotropic, how can I generate points on a sphere in this case? I know the existence of the Kent distribution, but I don't have the required quantities, like $'\gamma'$,$'\beta'$ and $'k'$. I don't know if there is a way to obtain those given a covariance matrix.
To further complicate the problem, the matrix is in 11 dimension but I need only the projection to the (distance,theta,phi)-space to then produce the map.
For now I tried to extract from a multivariate Gaussian but since the Gaussian is on the tangent plane, for some variances the distribution produce angles that are outside the domain for $'\theta'$ and $'\phi'$.
Here is the code I'm using to extract the points
num_samples = 10**7
samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(perm_mean, perm_cov, num_samples)

phi = samples[:, 2]
theta = samples[:, 1]
print(np.min(theta),np.max(theta))
print(np.min(phi),np.max(phi))
print('starting mean values')
print('theta={}, phi={}'.format(perm_mean[1],perm_mean[2]))

The point is that for some matrices, the variance is such that angles can go outside the domain. I can't act on the matrices, those are given to me by some other codes and should be treated as fixed data.
Thank you all in advance!

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try [stats.SE] instead.

Sorry didn't know is off topic. I delete this or simply post the same in Cross Validated?

@Raul yes, there was some form of Question transfer, but I'm not sure if it's still available - as this seems like a reasonable and well-formed Question, just repost it verbatim and comment here for the new post, we can then close this (no need to delete it can be a signpost for future users), Cross Validated also supports mathjax (hooray) - EDIT: actually there is a transfer to stats, so lets see

Thank you. I posted in the Cross Validated, I also added some more stuff to be clearer.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/654893/sampling-angles-on-a-sphere-from-a-general-covariance-matrix-to-concentration-p
